# check for removed slots in list

Tags: c#

I would like to generate some `Items` with IDs. `Item` is just a class with an ID integer attribute. They should get added to a list after creating them. So I have a class that manages all the items

```
internal static class ItemPool
{
    public static readonly List<Item> items = new List<Item>(); // Store all the items here

    public static Item CreateItem()
    {
        int itemId = items.Count; // Just take the next free slot index
        Item itemToCreate = new Item(itemId);
        items.Add(itemToCreate);
        return itemToCreate;
    }

    public static void DestroyItem(int itemId)
    {
        activeItems.RemoveAt(itemId);
    }
}
```

Now I can create some items

```
Item firstItem = ItemPool.CreateItem(); // generates item with ID 0

Item secondItem = ItemPool.CreateItem(); // generates item with ID 1

ItemPool.DestroyItem(firstItem.id); // Recudes the list count to 1

Item thirdItem = ItemPool.CreateItem(); // generates item with ID 1 - ERROR
```

The third item is not allowed to have the ID 1 because item 2 already has it.

When changing the code two questions come up:

How to manage the IDs for items in this list so that none of them have the same ID?

```
public static Item CreateItem()
{
    int itemId = temporaryUniqueId; // create a temporary unique ID
    // ... other code
}
```

What is a more optimized way than going for

```
public static void DestroyItem(int itemId)
{
    activeItems = activeItems.Where(item => item.id != itemId).ToList();
}
```

I know I could do

```
public static void DestroyItem(Item item)
{
    activeItems.Remove(item);
}
```

but I think removing by ID is more safe. I am asking this because for this case **performance is everything**.

**The IDs don't have to be integer values**

Comment: Is it a requirement to have the ID as an integer? Wouldn't it be easier for you to just use Guid and maybe a ConcurrentDictionary instead?

Comment: IMHO wouldn't the most easy way be to add another static field `Counter` to your static class and just increment it with each `CreateItem()`, taking it as the Id for the new Item?

Comment: Kzrystof no they don't have to be integers. A Dictionary would be a good idea

Comment: `Item is just a class with an ID integer attribute.` `The IDs don't have to be integer values.` It is a bit contradictory. What do you need that ID for? Do you need it at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since having an ID as an integer is not a requirement, one way to do this would be to use a `GUID` as a unique identifier to avoid having to deal with potential conflict.

```
public class Item 
{
    public Guid Id { get; }

    public Item()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

Then, your `ItemPool` class could be changed to use a `ConcurrentDictionary` (to avoid any race conditions):

```
internal sealed class ItemPool
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Item> items = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Item>(); // Store all the items here

    public Item CreateItem()
    {
        Item itemToCreate = new Item();
        items.TryAdd(itemToCreate.Id, itemToCreate);
        return itemToCreate;
    }

    public void DestroyItem(Guid itemId)
    {
        activeItems.TryRemove(itemId, out Item _);
    }
}
```

I took the liberty of removing the static parameter of the class to make it easier to test. I also made the `items` field private for better encapsulation. You do not want anyone other class to bypass `ItemPool` and start manipulating the collection by themselves :)

Comment: I have no idea and it does not matter that much when there are no comments :) If you think a solution fits your needs (whether it is my solution or someone else's), make sure to mark it as an accepted answer, upvote what you feel is correct or downvote what you feel is wrong.